# Integrating Angular 4 into ASP.NET Core MVC app - how to mix routing

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to integrate my Angular 4 app into asp.net mvc core project. And I'd like to have Angular app available within my Core MVC project with this Url - **mydomain.com/ngx**.

Here's how I do it now (and it doesn't work):

I build Angular app with angular-cli and use `ng build ... --base-href /ngx` (notice the **slash**). Then I copy everything from *dist* folder (where the build is placed by CLI) and copy it into `wwwroot/ngx` folder into my Core MVC project. But when I open `localhost/ngx/index.html` I get 404 errors for *main.bundle.js* and other js files. I checked the requests and for some reason it tries to get it as `localhost://main.bundle.js` - why from root?

now, if I build it with `--base-href ngx` (**no slash**) and open the site, it gets redirected to /ngx/ngx (doubles the ngx). so... wtf? :)

Core MVC routing doesn't have anything special, I haven't touched that part.

So how can I make it work as `localhost/ngx` ASP.NET Core MVC project?

Comment: Works fine here with `ng build --base-href /ngx/ --output-path dist/ngx`, running http-server from the dist directory, and going to `http://localhost:8080/ngx/index.html`.

Comment: Oh, man, thanks!!! Do you want me to add it as an answer or you'll do it yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works fine here with

```
ng build --base-href /ngx/ --output-path dist/ngx,
```

running http-server from the dist directory, and going to `http://localhost:8080/ngx/index.html`

Comment: I just found out that whatever you have in assets gets not found because it tries to get them from root (/assets/whatever) but it should try to get them from /ngx/assets/whatever. :(